# Working with JSON Web services in android

Tags: java, android, xml, json, web-services

I gave some value in edittext in URL some values will be there I have to call that URL using JSON webservice and display the total of these two values in other Edittext field in my layout  These are all happens in same layout in android  can you please help me with the code.

Comment: Hey put your code snipet here

Comment: First of all don't use chat shortcut's on SO, secondly paste the code what you have tried so far.

Comment: With the description it will me more wise if you put your code which you have tried so far and make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject detail =   new JSONArray(jsonString);
int p_id = Integer.parseInt(detail .getString("key"));
```

add `p_id`  to value in edit text

Comment: thank you ,i was in hurry so post it as it was in my notepad.